# compile statically linked test binary for code using net package in go 1.4.2

Tags: go

I am trying to create statically linked test binary for code which uses `net` package. But it gives me dynamically linked test binary. 
My code:

```
package main

import "net"

func main() {
    net.ParseIP("1.1.1.1")
}
```

Test:

```
package main

import "testing"

func TestMain(t *testing.T) {
    main()
}
```

I run command:

```
CGO_ENABLED=0 go test -c -installsuffix netgo -a -o ./static  && file ./static && ldd ./static
```

it gives:

```
./static: ELF 64-bit LSB  executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), not stripped
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffa1491000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f3ed433c000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f3ed3f77000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f3ed455a000)
```

If create non-test binary it works as I expect:

```
CGO_ENABLED=0 go build -installsuffix netgo -a -o ./static  && file ./static && ldd ./static
./static: ELF 64-bit LSB  executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, not stripped
not a dynamic executable
```

If I remove `net` package dependency or use go `1.6`, I can compile statically linked test binary. But I need do it with go 1.4.2 and `net` package dependency.

Also, I tried more flags:

```
go test -c -installsuffix netgo,cgo -tags netgo,cgo -ldflags '-s' -a -o ./static && file ./static && ldd ./static
```

But it gives me dynamically linked binary anyway.

Comment: I'm fairly certain that was a bug in go1.4. go1.4 is no longer supported for anything other than bootstrapping the compiler, so it would be much better to upgrade to a current version.

Comment: IIRC a workaround for go1.4 may have been to build the entire toolchain with `CGO_ENABLED=0`, you can give that a try.